# Access variable from controller within a respond_to js file

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm using Rails 3.1 and trying to add some ajax functionality (using jquery + coffeescript).

I have a  respond_to block in the controller

```
 def edit       
    @variable = 123
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
    end
  end
```

and a file app/views/test/edit.coffee.js

The file edit.coffee.js is be picked up and is running correctly, but I can't work out how to access `@variable` from the javascript.

Is there a way to pass this variable in to the js.coffee script? or do update an element on the page so that I can access it from the js.coffee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of your view file to `edit.coffee.js.erb` and then reference `@variable` ERB-style in your CoffeeScript:

```
some_method: ->
    console.log('<%=j @variable %>')
```

Answer (score 1):

With rails 3.2.1 I used

```
edit.js.coffee
```

and inside the template

```
alert '<%=j @variable %>'
```

to make this work.

I didn't work with the `.erb` suffix.